# Density and the projective tensor product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, tensor-products, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally convex space (over $\mathbb{R}$), $D\subset X$ be dense, $B$ be a Banach space (again over $\mathbb{R}$) with [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) $\{b_i\}_{i =1}^{\infty}$.  Is the set
$$
D^+\triangleq \left\{\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j d_j\otimes  b_j: \, d_j \in D, \, k_j \in \mathbb{R}
\right\}
,
$$
dense in $X\otimes E$ with respect to the [projective tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product#Tensor_products_of_locally_convex_topological_vector_spaces)?

Comment: Now it’s true.  If $E$ and $F$ are lcs’s with dense subsets $E_1$ and $F_1$, then the linear hull of the family of simple tensors they generate is dense in any of the sensible tensor products, in particular for the projective one.  By the way, I have deleted my comment, since it is now a nonsense, after the modification.

Comment: True, actually would it still remain true if $b_j$ are taken from a subset of $B$ with dense span instead of from all of $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be easy, mayby I am missing something: Given dense sets $D$ of $X$ and $E$ of $B$, a seminorm $p$ on $X$, $\varepsilon >0$, and $z=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_j \otimes y_j \in X\otimes B$ it is enough to $\varepsilon/n$-approximate with respect to $p\otimes_\pi \|\cdot\|$ each term of the sum by an element of $D \otimes E$. If $p(x_j -d)$ and $\|y_j-e\|$ are sufficiently small, we get from the bilinearity
$$ x_j\otimes y_j -d\otimes e = (x_j-d)\otimes y_j + d \otimes (y_j-e)$$ and hence 
$$(p\otimes_\pi \|\cdot\|)(x_j\otimes y_j -d\otimes e) \le p(x_j-d)\|y_j\| + p(d)\|y_j-e\| \le \varepsilon/n.$$